# Why isnt `(require 'use-package)` triggered when I open Emacs?

Tags: use-package, require

So, here is my `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package")
(require 'use-package)

(with-eval-after-load 'info
  (info-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'Info-directory-list
               "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/use-package/"))
```

`(use-package try :ensure t)` works only when I go next to `(add-to-list ...)` and press `C-x C-e` and then, next to `(require-package 'use-package)`, and pressing `C-x C-e`. Only if do this `use-package` is activated. When I close Emacs and re-open it I have to press `C-x C-e` again, and so on. How I can `use-package` remain active, so to speak; or how can it get triggered everytime I open Emacs?

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole file?

Comment: Any reason not to use the code in the use-package readme? https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#getting-started

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`. It's not clear at all whether or why a `(require 'use-package)` at the top level of your init file would not try to load `use-package`.

Comment: Emacs will look for an init file in a specific sequence: it will use the first one it finds. So if you have a `~/.emacs`  e.,g., the `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file is never going to be run. See [How Emacs finds  your init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above your init.el file is probably not loaded properly.

Please keep in mind that emacs has an particular order in which it searches for the initial init files.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init

`~/.emacs.el` > `~/.emacs` > `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

That also means if there is an `~/.emacs.el` emacs will not search for `~/.emacs`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` anymore

If you wish your init file to be `~/.emacs.d/init.el` please make sure that both of the other files don't exist.

Comment: I deleted `.emacs` and then reopened Emacs and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Emacs doesn't load your `init.el` file at startup.

Try to rename it as `~/.emacs`.

Comment: yeah, this make sense. I renamed it but it still not loading the file when I open Emacs.

Comment: It does not *automatically* make sense. See [Init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing Emacs27 and installing Emacs26 and then rebooting ie `reboot`.

Comment: If your init file isn't being read in Emacs 27 only, take note of https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS.27?h=master#n191